# How to search for a user in Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

It is simple to search for and find a user via Authentication with either an email, phone number or user ID.

Is there a way to search for a user via the Firebase Realtime Database?

Comment: Firebase Realtime Database has querying capabilities that you can read about in the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data

Comment: Are you asking how to search through Authenticated Users on the Firebase Authentication Server or how to search a /users node you've created for a specific user?

Comment: How to search for a user with children attached in the database. Not how to search for a user in the authentication tab which has no children.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to search is by querying, example:

```
var ref: DatabaseReference!

ref = Database.database().reference()
// My top posts by number of stars
let myTopPostsQuery = (ref.child("user-posts").child(getUid())).queryOrdered(byChild: "starCount")
```

> `queryorderedbyKey` :  Order results by child keys.
>
> `queryOrderedByValue` :    Order results by child values.
>
> `queryOrderedByChild` :    Order results by the value of a specified child key or nested child path

You can read more here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#filtering_data